# Result Excel Export from Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I have written the below Java code, which is executing fine in order to export the results in xlsx file from Oracle DB. But can someone help me to improve the performance of this code by which this below code can extract the result very fast.

Below is the Java Code which I have tried as of now; But it is slow while exporting result as compared to excel export from SQL Developer

```
public class FilesFromFolder {
    private Workbook writeWorkbook;

    public void ExportService(DBConnection con) {

        writeWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet desSheet = writeWorkbook.createSheet("Data");
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int columnsNumber = 0;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        Connection cntn = null;
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OracleExport";
        File files = new File(filePath);
        File[] file = files.listFiles();
        String fileNameWithOutExt = null;
        if (file != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                if (file[i].isFile()) {
                    String tempFilename = file[i].getName();
                    fileNameWithOutExt = tempFilename.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
                    File fileTemp = file[i];
                    try {
                        String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(fileTemp, "UTF8");
                        // System.out.println(fileContent);
                        cntn = con.getConnection();
                        stmt = cntn.createStatement();
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery(fileContent);
                        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                        columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                        Row desRow1 = desSheet.createRow(0);
                        for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
                            Cell newpath = desRow1.createCell(col);
                            newpath.setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col + 1));
                        }
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println("Row number -->" + rs.getRow());
                            Row desRow = desSheet.createRow(rs.getRow());
                            for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
                                Cell newpath = desRow.createCell(col);
                                newpath.setCellValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
                            }
                            String outputFile = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OracleExport\\" + fileNameWithOutExt
                                    + ".xlsx";
                            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                            writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
                        }
                        System.out.println(fileNameWithOutExt + " export complete");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (fileOut!= null) {
                            try {
                                fileOut.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (cntn != null) {
                            con.closeConnection();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might get better performance with SXSSFWorkbook (a streaming version of XSSFWorkbook). Have you tried using a Java Profiling tool to see what the hotspots are?

Comment: Hi PJ, Thanks for your suggestion. But If someone can make adjustments on this code then it would be better. Is it possible ?

Comment: PJ,I have updated my code like [writeWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();] & rest of the code is same. But it is giving me error at 2nd Iteration like [java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SheetDataWriter.beginRow(SheetDataWriter.java:210)]] ...... Can you please help / advise on this ?

Comment: `fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);` should not be inside the while loop. You should only write the SXSSFWorkbook once.

Comment: While I am exporting the data from DB I am experienceing below exception. Can you please advise on this... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[0] in the range [0,57] that is already written to disk.